# What does this pseudo code mean?- Binary Search Tree Successor Function

Tags: binary-search-tree

```
if right[x] != NIL
 then return TREE-MINIMUM(right[x])

 y<-p[x]
 while y!= NIL and x = right[y]
  do x<-y
  y<-p[y]
 return y
```

I know what "if right[x] != NIL then return tree-min" means and I've translated it to:

```
if(p->RChild) return fMinValue(p->RChild);//returns the min value of the sub-tree starting at the right child node of p
```

The rest I'm having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<-` is most likely the assignment operator. `p` I would guess is parent. What else are you confused about?

Comment: p[x] and p[y]. Is p a pointer and the contents of [] is what p is pointing to?

Edit: =) It makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: The way I'm reading it, `p[x]` is a function which returns the parent of node `x`. `right[x]` would be the right child of `x` then.

Answer (score 2):

Here `p[]` almost certainly means "the parent node of". You're working on node `x`, so `p[x]` means "the parent of the current node" (just like `right[x]` means "the right-hand child of the current node").

The `<-` notation is assignment. Like `=` in c-like languages.

The second part of the algorithm presented here walks up the tree looking for the first time you ascended a left link instead of a right one. But I'm not sure that I would describe this as a successor function.