# What does "!" mean in pseudo-code? I know "!" stands for factorial but I can't translate it

Tags: javascript, operators, pseudocode

What does `!` mean in pseudo-code? I know `!` stands for factorial but I can't translate it .

ex:

get operation

```
if (operation!= ’B’ OR operation != ’D’ OR operation!= ’W’) then
    print "Invalid Operation"
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Interesting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304809/what-does-this-pseudo-code-mean-binary-search-tree-successor-function/2458716#2458716) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "not".  So your example code

```
if (operation!= ’B’ OR operation != ’D’ OR operation!= ’W’)
```

can be read as

> "If operation does not equal 'B' or operation does not equal 'D' or operation does not equal 'W'"

Answer (score 6):

`!=` means not equal and `!` generally means *not* or *negation*.

Answer (score 5):

In *general*,

> `!`   means   **not**
>   `||` means `logical` **or**
>   `&&` means `logical` **and**

Example:

```
!false == true  ( == means equality )
```

Comment: Sorry, it had to be said. I certainly prefer pseudo-code as language-agnostic as possible. It's usually not paradigm-agnostic, though.

Comment: so does this meaning "not" apply to jave or not?

Comment: @Dina yes, `!` is the logical not operator in Java.

Comment: @Dina: yes `!` means `not` in java

Comment: So, what that pseudo-code half C and half pascal? C doesn't have `OR` but `||`.